# how to return two values in a tuple in python function

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

i need to solve a task:
a function `filter_list` that takes only one argument (a list of integers) and returns two values in a tuple

1. sum of elements of the list that are >= 13 and <= 97
2. sum of elements of the list that are >0 and 13-fold

So i have a conceptual understanding of how that could be achieved, however when i start writing my code, i can't assign those two values to a new variable outside the function.

```
numbers = [1, 10, 13, 23, 34, 45, 90]

    def filter_list(nums):
        for e in nums:
            result1 = sum(e for e in nums if e >= 13 and e <= 97)
            return result1
        for e in nums:
            result2 = sum(e for e in nums if e>0 and e % 13 == 0)
            return result2
        print(result1, result2)
    
print(filter_list(numbers))

result_sum = filter_list(numbers)

print(result_sum)
```

Comment: Once you hit a `return` statement the function exits and won't continue running. So for the first iteration of your first for loop, it will exit. It will never reach any other iteration and it certainly won't hit the second for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def filter_list(nums):
    result1 = sum(e for e in nums if 97 >= e >= 13)
    result2 = sum(e for e in nums if e > 0 and e % 13 == 0)
    print(result1, result2)
    return result1, result2
```

You don't need to do a `for loop` then inside it another. Also after you `return` the function is exited and you can no longer do anything. So you have to store the variables then return them at once.

Answer (score 1):

```
def filter_list(nums):
    for e in nums:
        result1 = sum(e for e in nums if e >= 13 and e <= 97)
        result2 = sum(e for e in nums if e>0 and e % 13 == 0)
    return (result1,result2)

numbers = [1, 10, 13, 23, 34, 45, 90]

result_sum = filter_list(numbers)

print(result_sum)
```

**Output** : (205, 13)

I have just done a small correction in your code.

A function won't execute after a return statement.

In your case the function returns the result1 and get backs to the main code.

Edit:

```
 def filter_list(nums):
    result1 = sum(e for e in nums if e >= 13 and e <= 97)
    result2 = sum(e for e in nums if e>0 and e % 13 == 0)
return (result1,result2)

numbers = [1, 10, 13, 23, 34, 45, 90]

result_sum = filter_list(numbers)

print(result_sum)
```

**Output** : (205, 13)

Comment: You have a problem in your code, which is similar to the problem in his code, which is the double `for loop` concept. You don't need the first `for loop` if you're summing the internal loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't concentrate on logic, just trying to make a clear in functions, thanks mate :)